# Is this inequality right

Tags: calculus

> If $f''(x)>0$ show that $$\frac{f(x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_n)}{n}<\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)+f(x_3)...+f(x_n)}{n}$$

please provide a hint about how this problem can be solved.

I just verified it for $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: Please read about [convex function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) and try to generalize it for your case.

Comment: Use a '\' in front of frac and dont use '/'

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality might help you.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**

The inequality appears to have a typo. As written, it implies

$$f(x_1+\dots +x_n) < f(x_1) + \dots + f(x_1).$$

But this is wrong for $f(x) =x^2$, because for $a,b>0$, $(a+b)^2 > a^2 + b^2$.

The correct inequality is

$$ f (\frac{x_1+ \dots + x_n}{n}) \le \frac {f(x_1) +\dots + f(x_n)}{n},$$

with equality if and only if $x_1=\dots = x_n$.

Proof:

Use Taylor's expansion: 
$$ f(b)= f(a) + f'(a) (b-a) + f''(c)\frac{(b-a)^2}{2}.$$

where $c$ is an intermediate point. Since $f''(c)>0$, we have

$$   f(b) \ge f(a) + f'(a) (b-a),$$

whenever $a\ne b$, with equality if and only if $a=b$.

Now write the inequality for $a$ and $b_i$, $i=1,\dots,n$ and sum, to obtain:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n f(b_i) \ge  n f(a) + f'(a) \sum_{i=1}^n (b_i -a),$$

with equality if and only if all $b_1=b_2 = \dots=b_n=a$.

Now time to choose:

$$a= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n b_i}{n}.$$

Then the summation on the right hand side is zero and we obtain

$$ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n f (b_i)}{n} \ge f(a).$$

the result follows, with an equality if and only if all $b_i$'s are the same.

Answer (score 0):

since $f''(x)>0$ then $f$ is **strictly convex** function $\implies$ $f((1-t)x_1+tx_2)\lt(1-t)f(x_1)+tf(x_2)$

for $t\in [0,1]$

Now $f(x_1)+f(x_2)=f((x_1+x_2)\frac{x_1}{x_1+x_2})+f((x_1+x_2)\frac{x_2}{x_1+x_2}) $

$\lt \frac{x_1}{x_1+x_2}f(x_1+x_2)+\frac{x_1}{x_1+x_2}f(x_1+x_2)=f(x_1+x_2)$ $\implies$ $\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)}{2}\lt \frac{f(x_1+x_2)}{2}$

(since $\frac{x_1}{x_1+x_2} \in [0,1]$ )

Now by Mathematical induction on $n$ , assume the inquality above is true for $n=k$ . We want to prove that it's true for $n=k+1$ .

$\frac{f((x_1+x_2+...+x_k)+x_{k+1})}{k+1}\lt \frac{ f((x_1+x_2+...+x_k)+f(x_{k+1})}{k+1}\lt \frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)+...+f(x_k)+f(x_{k+1})}{K+1}$
Thus it's true for n=k+1 , then by mathematical induction it's true for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

This is my attempt to answer your question , If there is any wrong step please tell me .